React Build Failing on Vercel: Module Not Found 'react-dom/client'
I'm having an issue with deploying my React application on Vercel. The build process keeps failing with the following error:
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-dom/client' in '/vercel/path0/src'
Context:
React Version: 17.0.2
React-Scripts Version: 4.0.3
Build Tool: Vercel
Dependencies:
My package.json includes:
{
  "name": "book-tracker",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dnd": "^16.0.1",
    "react-dnd-html5-backend": "^16.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "^4.0.3",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.10",
    "web-vitals": "^4.2.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "CI=false react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}


I've added @babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object to devDependencies.

I ensured I was using Node.js version 16 by configuring it locally using nvm.

Asked chatGPT 4-o, which has been completely unhelpful

restarted my computer and reinstalled everything


Issue:
The deployment works perfectly fine locally, but on Vercel, it fails with the error above. I've ensured that all necessary dependencies are installed and configured.
Question:
Has anyone else encountered this issue, and if so, how did you resolve it? Any guidance or tips would be greatly appreciated!
